# Link to different angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I have two different AngularJS applications hosted on different servers. I want to be able to have a link in one application to the other. How can I do this? Is it just as simple as adding an href to a url that loads the other module from the other server?

Note that these are two completely different modules with different dependencies and routes.

Update: by link, I mean have one SPA link to a different SPA

Comment: define `link`. It sounds like you want to import one app into another but your terminology and explanation are not clear

Comment: I'm not sure as well, but you can create `a` tag with `href` that point to other server. Nothing related to angular.